# MISRA C: Type casting and <<, & bit-wise operators error

Tags: c, embedded, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, misra

I've been having a lot of trouble with MISRA when doing << and & operations.

Definitions of types for context

```
typedef uint32_t uint32;
typedef volatile uint32* canreg_txrx_pointer;
canreg_txrx_pointer canreg_txrx;
uint8_t valueRead, value;
#define CAN_DIR_BIT_POS ((uint8_t)2U)
#define CAN_OUT_BIT_POS ((uint8_t)1U)
#define CAN_IN_BIT_POS ((uint8_t)0U)
```

When trying to perform a series of << and & operations on the registers, I continually get the error `#1397-D (MISRA-C:2004 10.5/R) If the bitwise operators ~ and << are applied to an operand of underlying type unsigned char or unsigned short, the result shall be immediately cast to the underlying type of the operand`

An example that doesn't pass the misra check and then an example that does is given below

```
*canreg_txrx = (uint32)((*canreg_txrx & (~(uint32)(1U << CAN_OUT_BIT_POS))) | (uint32)(value << CAN_OUT_BIT_POS)); //doesn't pass MISRA
valueRead = (uint8_t)(((uint8_t)*regToOperateOn & (uint8_t)(1U << CAN_OUT_BIT_POS)) >> CAN_OUT_BIT_POS); //passes MISRA
```

I've tried multiple changes to the offending line where none of them have resulted in MISRA letting it through (except randomly where it just gives me no warnings) to the point where I decided to cast everything and that still doesn't work

```
*canreg_txrx = (uint32)((*canreg_txrx & (uint32)(~(uint32)((uint32)1U << (uint32)CAN_OUT_BIT_POS))) | (uint32)((uint32)value << (uint32)CAN_OUT_BIT_POS)); //doesn't pass MISRA
```

I'm really confused on how to fix this code so that it will pass MISRA as this  bitwise logic is used in multiple places and all of them don't pass. I assumed that if everything is cast to the same type then there should really be no issue since it's all operating at the same type but for some reason that doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you doing all those typedefs?

Comment: The typedefs aren't part of any code I control, I just included them to make it apparent what my used types were.

Comment: Can I politely suggest you read that rationale for the Rule, when all becomes clear?

Comment: @Andrew In all fairness, that rationale does you no good unless you realize that some tool might regard `1U` as a potential small integer type. The OP is apparently using a 32 bitter so that's not the case here.

Comment: Overall, you might at a minimum need to configure a MISRA checker so that it knows 1) how larger your integer type `int` is, and 2) which type that you are using corresponds to "essentially boolean". It can't know these things out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used Misra but I find your code hard to read with all that noise of typedefs, casts and parenthesis.  My suggestion would be to simplify and split the problem into smaller parts along these lines:

```
*canreg_txrx = (uint32)((*canreg_txrx & (~(uint32)(1U << CAN_OUT_BIT_POS))) | (uint32)(value << CAN_OUT_BIT_POS)); // =>

*canreg_txrx &= ~(1U << CAN_OUT_BIT_POS);
*canreg_txrx |= value << CAN_OUT_BIT_POS; // maybe =>

#define BIT_CLEAR(val, pos) ((val) &= ~(1U << (pos)))
BIT_CLEAR(*canreg_txrx, CAN_OUT_BIT_POS);
*canreg_txrx |= value << CAN_OUT_BIT_POS; // *
```

'*' If value is a bit, then this is just bit set, otherwise can't think of good name.

Then run it through Misra and *only* fix what it complains about.

Comment: +1 for the split into multiple statements. @astroturfdurf If you need to read `*canreg_txrx` only once before writing to it, use a temporary variable. The generated machine code will be exactly the same as for your complex statement, most probably.

Comment: Isn't it much simpler to `#define CAN_OUT_BIT_MASK 0x02u` (etc) rather than define a bit position and shift it?

Comment: @Andrew The problem is that you introduce a 2nd magic value 2u and the only relation with the macro that defines the position is the name. If they ever change, you now have to remember to change both the position the mask. The new define introduce name pollution so if it was my code I would introduce suitable macros (BIT_SET, BIT_CLEAR) but that could make it harder to read.  I considered it originally but decided not as to keep the solution simple.

Comment: But if you use the mask, you don't need the bit?

Comment: There are traditionally two common styles used: `#define PIN 0x02u` or `#define PIN (1u << 1)`. Either is fine. The Arduino/AVR hype seems to have dragged a 3rd, brittle style into the embedded world: `#define POS 2  ...  PIN = 1 << POS;` (yes, they use signed integer constants while shifting on a 8 bitter MCU, what could go wrong).

Answer (score 0):

MISRA-C is a bit confused since it insists on a cast to "underlying type" (MISRA-C:2004 term) *after* the shift has been done. I prefer to do the cast to a large unsigned type *before* the shift, since that rules out all problems that can happen.

What these rules strive to prevent is an accidental conversion to a signed type through [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules) followed by something like a bit shift, which could be dangerous and cause various bugs, including change of signedness, accidental sign extension, undefined behavior upon left shifting signed values, impl.defined behavior upon right shifting them, and so on.

In your case, you get these problems specifically because you are not casting the result of the `~` to the underlying type here: `~(uint32)(1U << CAN_OUT_BIT_POS))`. It appears that your static analyser is giving a false positive, since the underlying type here appears to be `uint32_t`. There is no smaller type to account for unless since you appear to have have 32 bit integers (since you have 32 bit CAN registers) , but the tool might not know that your integers are 32 bits, in which case `1U` could have been a 16 bit value.

Otherwise, maybe the tool is getting confused because you use confused casts when defining those macros... but for the shift operators specifically, the type of the right operand does not matter (though it's promoted too).

In this particular case, none of this should be dangerous since you expect unsigned 32. The warnings, the casts, everything - it's just noise, turning your code brittle and unreadable.

I'd suggest you salvage the code in the following manner:

- Get rid of all the `uint8` casts from the macros, that's just noise and potentially causing problems.
- Get rid of the home-brewed `uint32` etc types and use standard C `uint32_t`. `typedef uint32_t uint32;` is rotten code that shouldn't exist in any C program. Use the existing industry standards, don't invent new ones.
- Don't hide pointers behind typedefs, that's very dangerous practice which makes the code hard to read.
- Get rid of superfluous casts. Assuming this is a 32 bitter, you shouldn't cast `1U` types to `uint32_t` since they are the same type already.
- Break up unreadable lines into several expressions. For example we can do `const uint32_t mask = ~(1U << CAN_OUT_BIT_POS);`. There should be no need to cast since the underlying type is already `uint32_t`. Your MISRA checker might be too dumb to realize that you have 32 bit integers though, so you might have to add a cast `(uint32_t)~ ...`. Not for MISRA-C:2004 compliance but to silence a potentially dumb tool.
- In case you just need to cast to silence a particular tool, you should make an explicit comment about that: `/* this cast just to silence BrokenAnalyser from Bugworks */`. To show that you know what you are doing and that you separate false positives from actual necessary casts.
- Another valid concern of MISRA-C is that you shouldn't be doing multiple accesses to `volatile` registers in the same expression, since this introduces unsequenced side effects, plus you can't really tell when and where on that line the actual register access happens, plus it blocks compiler optimizations. This is another MISRA violation that you have not yet spotted. This can also be solved by breaking up the long expression into several.

One example:

```
const uint32_t mask = ~(1U << CAN_OUT_BIT_POS);
uint32_t txrx = *canreg_txrx; // volatile access on a line of its own
txrx = (txrx & mask) | ((uint32_t)value << CAN_OUT_BIT_POS);
*canreg_txrx = txrx;
```

The middle txrx line will get optimized and in the machine code you'll just get a few instructions anyway. This should be MISRA-C:2004 and 2012 compliant, far as I can tell. This also doesn't shift the implicitly promoted `value` and then cast afterwards.